# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - osascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a Rails app which i am trying to deploy in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Linux. `bundle install` run ok but when I run `bundle exec rake secret` it shows `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - osascript`

```
myappuser@ubuntu:/var/www/myapp/code$ bundle exec rake secret
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - osascript
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/webconsole-0.2.1/lib/webconsole/lib/module.rb:95:in ``'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/webconsole-0.2.1/lib/webconsole/lib/module.rb:95:in `run_applescript'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/webconsole-0.2.1/lib/webconsole/lib/module.rb:10:in `application_exists'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/webconsole-0.2.1/lib/webconsole.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/myapp/code/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/myapp/code/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/var/www/myapp/code/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

`webconsole` is trying to run `osascript`, which is macOS-specific and not available on Linux. You can replace `gem 'webconsole'` in your Gemfile with the following to only use it on macOS:

```rb
gem 'webconsole' if RUBY_PLATFORM.match?(/darwin/)
```